# How can I determine whether a C++ class has any pointer/reference data members?

Tags: c++, serialization, type-traits

I'm writing some code which will generically (i.e. using `memcpy`) serialize C++ objects and then deserialize them in a different process.  I would like to statically assert that this is safe for the types being used.

I know that `std::is_trivially_copyable` will tell me if the type can safely be copied with `memcpy`, but in order for the serialization/deserialization to be safe across address spaces, I need to further ensure that the class contains no (non-static) pointer or reference members, which after deserialization would point to nonsense addresses.

Is it possible to determine this in C++?

Comment: no, but you can explicitly statically assert it for all classes where it's true.

Comment: Unless the two processes are compiled with the same compiler, using the same compiler options, on the same machine, even `int` is unsafe.  (In shared memory, however, I would expect that the collaborating processes do meet these requirements.)